# Prime Number Theorem/GRH versus estimations

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Sometimes I believe elementary clues are lacking to me:

**First instance (PNT).** I have a Schwartz function $\phi$, whose Fourier transform $\widehat{\phi}$ has support in $(-2,2)$. *Why does prime number theorem implies that*
$$\sum_p \widehat{\phi}\left(\frac{2\log p}{\log R}\right)\frac{2\log p}{p\log R} = \frac{1}{2} \phi(0) + O\left(\frac{1}{\log R}\right) ?$$

is there any transformation hiding behing this fact? (I have tried replacing the Fourier transform by its definition and operating in order to get some Mertens' estimates to do...)

**Second instance (GRH).** With the same assumptions as above, $f$ an holomorphic cusp form of weight $k$ and level $N$, $\lambda_f(p^2)$ its Hecke eigenvalues, *why does the Riemann hypothesis for* $L(s, \mathrm{sym}^2 f)$ (which has coefficients $\lambda_f(p^2)$) *implies that*
$$\sum_p \lambda_f(p^2) \widehat{\phi}\left(\frac{2\log p}{\log R}\right)\frac{2\log p}{p\log R} = O\left(\frac{\log \log kN}{\log R}\right) ?$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you're reading ILS! Anyway, since the support of $\widehat{\phi}$ is in $(-2,2)$, we can write the first sum as
\[\frac{2}{\log R} \sum_{p \leq R} \widehat{\phi}\left(\frac{2 \log p}{\log R}\right) \frac{\log p}{p}.\]
We use partial summation to write this as
\[\frac{2}{\log R} \widehat{\phi}\left(\frac{2 \log R}{\log R}\right) \sum_{p \leq R} \frac{\log p}{p} - \frac{2}{\log R} \int_{1}^{R} \sum_{p \leq t} \frac{\log p}{p} \frac{d}{dt} \widehat{\phi}\left(\frac{2 \log t}{\log R}\right) \, dt.\]
The first term vanishes as the support of $\widehat{\phi}$ is in $(-2,2)$. By the prime number theorem,
\[\sum_{p \leq t} \frac{\log p}{p} = \log t + O(1).\]
We use this split the integral into two sums. Using integration by parts, the main term is equal to
\[\frac{2}{\log R} \int_{1}^{R} \frac{1}{t} \widehat{\phi}\left(\frac{2 \log t}{\log R}\right) \, dt.\]
We make the change of variables $u = \frac{2 \log t}{\log R}$, so that it becomes
\[\int_{0}^{2} \widehat{\phi}(u) \, du,\]
which, by the fact that $\widehat{\phi}(u)$ is even and supported in $(-2,2)$, is equal to
\[\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \widehat{\phi}(u) \, du = \frac{1}{2} \phi(0).\]
For the error term, we note that
\[\frac{1}{\log R} \int_{1}^{R} \left|\frac{d}{dt} \widehat{\phi}\left(\frac{2 \log t}{\log R}\right)\right| \, dt = \frac{2}{(\log R)^2} \int_{1}^{R} \frac{1}{t} \left|\widehat{\phi}'\left(\frac{2 \log t}{\log R}\right)\right| \, dt.\]
Since $\widehat{\phi}$ is supported in $(-2,2)$, so is $\widehat{\phi}'$, and so
\[\int_{1}^{R} \frac{1}{t}  \left|\widehat{\phi}'\left(\frac{2 \log t}{\log R}\right)\right| \, dt \ll \int_{1}^{R} \frac{1}{t} \, dt = \log R.\]
Putting everything together, we see that
\[\sum_{p} \widehat{\phi}\left(\frac{2 \log p}{\log R}\right) \frac{2 \log p}{p \log R} = \frac{1}{2} \phi(0) + O\left(\frac{1}{\log R}\right).\]

For the second sum in your question, we use the same method of proof, writing this as
\[\frac{2}{\log R} \widehat{\phi}\left(\frac{2 \log R}{\log R}\right) \sum_{p \leq R} \frac{\lambda_f(p^2) \log p}{p} - \frac{2}{\log R} \int_{1}^{R} \sum_{p \leq t} \frac{\lambda_f(p^2) \log p}{p} \frac{d}{dt} \widehat{\phi}\left(\frac{2 \log t}{\log R}\right) \, dt.\]
Then the generalised Riemann hypothesis for $L(s, \mathrm{sym}^2 f)$ implies that
\[\sum_{p \leq t} \frac{\lambda_f(p^2) \log p}{p} = O(\log \log kN),\]
from which the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you only need to say that $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on $\Re(s) = 1$ :

---

Let $F(s) = \frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-\zeta(s)$. Then $f(\xi)= F(1+2 i\pi \xi)$ is the Fourier transform of the distribution $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)-1}{n} \delta(x-\ln n)$$  where $\Lambda(n) = \ln p$ if $n = p^k$ (which is almost the same as $\vartheta(n) = \ln p$ if $n=p$)

Let $\phi_A(x) = \phi(Ax)$ so that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)-1}{A n} \hat{\phi}(\frac{\ln n}{A}) = \langle \hat{\phi}_A,\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)-1}{n} \delta(x-\ln n)\rangle = \langle \phi_A, f \rangle$$

Since $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on $\Re(s) = 1$, then $f$ is continuous at $0$ and polynomially bounded, and since $\phi$ is $C^\infty_c$ 
$$\langle \phi_A, f \rangle = \mathcal{O}(1/A )$$

So it leaves us with
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{A n} \hat{\phi}(\frac{\ln n}{A}) $$

....